# fullcalendar d'ont display data with contains datetime

Tags: fullcalendar, laravel-5.6

Hi friends i'am using maddhatter fullcalendar in my project laravel 5.6,when i fetch my data in calendar its work by data contains format y-m-d but when i change my format to datetime my camlendar does not display anything this my code:

```
$events = Agenda::where('code_commercial', $code)->get();
$event_list = [];
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $event_list[] = Calendar::event(
            $event->description,
            true,
            date_format(date_create($event->date_debut), "Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            date_format(date_create($event->date_fin), "Y-m-d H:i:s")
            // new \DateTime($event->date_debut),
            // new \DateTime($event->date_fin),
            // Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $event->date_debut)->toDateTimeString(),
            // Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $event->date_fin)->toDateTimeString()

        );
    }
```

and this is my configuration for fullcalendar :

```
 $calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list, [ //set custom color 
 fo this event
            'color' => '#800',
        ])->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options

            'firstDay' => 1,
            'selectable' => true,
            'defaultView' => 'agendaWeek',
            'allDay' => false,
            'slotLabelFormat' => 'HH:mm:ss',
            'editable' => true,
            'eventLimit' => true,
            // 'minTime' => '07:00:00',
            // 'maxTime' => '22:00:00',
            // 'slotDuration' => '01:30:00',

        ])
```

please any help thanks for you

Comment: Please show us the actual JSON being generated by your code, thanks.

Comment: this is my data geted from database :  $events = Agenda::where('code_commercial', $code)->get();  i d'ont have JSON, Note : Iam Using package Maddhatter Fullcalendar in laravel 5.6. thanks for you

Comment: you must be turning your data in to JSON (or directly into JavaScript objects) in order for fullCalendar to use it.

Comment: after shearch  i ge ta  solution just use false  instead of true here :      
      $event_list[] = Calendar::event($event->description . " " . $event->cp,
      true,      change by : $event_list[] = Calendar::event(
      $event->description . " " . $event->cp,
      false,   it work

Comment: false instead of true for what, exactly? And what does that have to do with dates??. If you have a solution you should post a clear explanation of it in the Answers section so everyone can understand. Thanks.

Comment: Because true - it's mean a full-day event

Comment: Ok I see. Great that you solved it. You should post it in the Answers section, as I mentioned.